# Using JQuery to find the contents of a td tag

Tags: jquery

Im in the process of learning JQuery and trying to get the contents of a particular td tag. Here is my table and here is my code to try to get the contents. If you could point what im doing wrong, it would be very appreciated. When I click the button the alert message give me a blank.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="hamburger">Hamburger</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
alert($("#hamburger").text);
```

Comment: More on topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421891/1338846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'#'` character in the selector is to choose an element by the id.
You should write your selector like this : `'.hamburger'`

also, the 'text' method you're using, needs to be called like this : `$('.hamburger').text()`

using the '`.`' (**dot**) character in the beginning of the selector, means you're looking for an element by it's class name.

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a function, so you need to call it as a function:

```
alert( $('.hamburger').text();
```

Also, you are trying to reference `hamburger` as an ID, not a class; see above how I've used a dot instead of a hash to select it.

Answer (score 0):

replace # with . in your selector. # is for id

```
$(".hamburger").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`hamburger` is a class name so use . for selection. text is a method. not a property.

```
 alert($(".hamburger").text());
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/yAqLU/1/

use **dot** for selecting with css class names

use **#** for selecting with element Id